# for loop with multiple variables in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to parse a file which has the following:
 `result(x1 y1 x2 y2... xn yn)`
This is a piece of code in python I have written. I am new to python.

```
xs =[] ys=[]

def __init__(self,xs,ys):
        self.xs = xs
        self.ys = ys


def toString(self):
    return "result " + " (" + " ".join([x.toString()+ " " + y.toString() for x,y in zip(self.xs, self.ys)]) + ") "
```

I am getting `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'toString'` error on running. Please suggest how to fix this.

Comment: just making sure: all of this is in a class right? because else the 'self' doesn't make sense

Comment: yes. The first line is written before the invoking. To parse result(x1 x2 ...xn) I have the following code which works fine. def toString(self):
        return "result " + " ".join([x.toString() for x in self.xs]) + ")"    I need to write in this form.

Answer (score 2):

Strings in Python don't have a `toString()` method.  You can use `str(your_variable)` instead.  If the variables are already strings, you don't need to do anything special.